# AJAX request doesn't work the first time but works thereafter

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, readystate

I'm making a simple function as it is shown on w3schools official website. I'm trying to run a function of an AJAX request.

I guess it's all working well except the fact that the code ONLY runs after it fails the first time. I mean, let's say you just came the first time to my website and you try to submit the first time, it just refreshes the page and nothing happens.

As far as I'm aware I tried to debug using `alert` functions in each line to find if the request was really being made. I found that the `readyState` jumps from 1 to 4 the very first time the code runs (in every browser, different computers), but next time it will render readyState 1, 2, 3 and 4 and BANG it will work and submit.

**Javascript function code** (inside head tag)

```
function sendForm() {
        
    var criarRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    criarRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {  
        if (criarRequest.readyState == 4 && criarRequest.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("contacts").innerHTML = criarRequest.responseText;
        } 
    };
    //var loading  = document.getElementById("contacts").innerHTML = "A enviar...";
    var inputEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var inputMensagem = document.getElementById("mensagem").value;  
    criarRequest.open("POST", "sendEmail.php", true);
    criarRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    criarRequest.send("email="+inputEmail+"&mensagem="+inputEmail);
}
```

**HTML code form/inputs**

```
<form>
    <input style="width:220px; height:39px" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" /> 
    <br  /> <br  />
    <textarea style="width:220px; height:100px" id="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
    <br  /> <br  />
    <button id="enviar" onclick="sendForm()">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

actually very simple:P your button is default attribute 'type' of "submit" and when that happens, the form gets submitted causing a refresh. Add 'type="button"' to change this functionality and you should not have a refresh anymore allowing the ajax to finish its request.

Comment: THANK you so much! So simple it is working now. I can't believe I've lost so many hours reviewing my js code.

Comment: Do you know why it will work after the first "failed" submit?

Comment: Not totally sure why but it should refresh every time. The only reason i can see it working is that your server cached the results and is seeing the same request so it has a quicker response, but it is still refreshing. Is your page still refreshing after the first click?

Comment: The problem was solved when I did what you said, setting the type to "button". It's been working :)

Comment: You just saved my life! Thank you * 100