# ASP.NET Core MVC first submit button click returns error (Aborted Session)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I am totally new to this an I am trying to learn how to do API calls from JS using Ajax.

I started an ASP.NET Core web application using MVC.

I created an HTML form in the Index.cshtml with a submit button ( I would like to use some razor features in the future when I master this!)

```
<form id="login_form">

    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="GeneralPost()"/>

</form>
```

What I noticed is that the first time I click the submit button after I start the debug mode from visual studio (the server runs) returns an error.But the later button clicks returns a success!

Here is my Ajax that I put in the site.js folder

```
function GeneralPost() {
var  data = "Data To Pass";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/Login',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.name);              
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error");
    }

});
}
```

And here is my controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{

    // What I wrote 
    [HttpPost()]
    public User Login([FromBody]string data)
    {

        User user = new User(); ;
        user.name = $"User {data}";
        user.id = "1";
        return user;

    }

    // the rest is already there from the MVC example by visual studio (deleted some code to make it shorter)
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

I also noticed that when I click submit button on the razor page, the Index() action gets executed. I am not sure why the Index action is executed all the time when I requested the Login action! is it something with MVC? Is this behavior related to my first request to get aborted!

I think it's also a good idea to include my configuration from Startup.cs since I am not sure if I understand the whole thing yet and I am trying to provide as much helpful information as I can

```
      // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }


       // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
    }
```

To summarize this:

1- The first time I press the submit button after I start the debug session from visual studio, I get Error and Fiddler shows me that the Session State is Aborted.

2- The second time that I press the button even if it's on a new tab or a new browser I get the expected results with no errors.

Any ideas? I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on the following question

[AJAX request doesn't work the first time but works thereafter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953199/ajax-request-doesnt-work-the-first-time-but-works-thereafter)
I guess I was using the wrong search key words!

basically the form was of type submit. Thus, it refreshes the page when I hit the submit button and that causes the request to be interfered and aborted.